# How to write OLS criterion in terms of OLS regression error?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, least-squares, econometrics

I'm learning OLS criterion (minimize the sample analog of Mean Square Error). And in one part the slide said OLS criterion can be written as:

$Q_n(\beta)=\frac{1}{n}\hat{U}^T\hat{U}+(\beta-\hat{\beta})^T\frac{X^TX}{n}(\beta-\hat{\beta})$

Where $\hat{U}$ is the regression error that equal to $Y-\hat{Y}$

I try to prove this, and my trial is as follows:

$Q_n(\beta)=\frac{1}{n}(Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X\beta)=\frac{1}{n}(Y-X\hat{\beta}+X\hat{\beta}-X\beta)^T(Y-X\hat{\beta}+X\hat{\beta}-X\beta)=\frac{1}{n}(\hat{U}-X(\beta-\hat{\beta}))^T(\hat{U}-X(\beta-\hat{\beta}))=\frac{1}{n}\hat{U}^T\hat{U}+\frac{1}{n}\hat{U}^TX(\hat{\beta}-\beta)+\frac{1}{n}(\hat{U}^TX(\hat{\beta}-\beta))^T+
(\beta-\hat{\beta})^T\frac{X^TX}{n}(\beta-\hat{\beta})$

So for me, there is always this term in the middle ($\frac{1}{n}\hat{U}^TX(\hat{\beta}-\beta)+\frac{1}{n}(\hat{U}^TX(\hat{\beta}-\beta))^T$) that I cannot get rid of.

Can someone tell me where I did wrong, and what should be the right proof?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figure it out, that since we minimize Q, we can get normal equation (first order equation) that make the middle two terms equal to 0. The detail is here：

$Q_n(\beta)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{}^{}(Y_{i}-\hat{\beta} X_i)^{2}$

$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \beta}=0 \longrightarrow \frac{1}{n}\sum_{}^{}X_{i}(Y_i-\hat{\beta} X_i)=0$

where $Y_i-\hat{\beta} X_i=\hat{U_i}$, hence:

$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{}^{}X_i\hat{U_i}=0$

$\frac{1}{n}X^{T}\hat{U}=0$

Hence, the middle 2 terms becomes 0.

Tell me if there is anything wrong!

Best!